# BS HTML Parsing - &amp; is ignored when printing URL strings

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

Consider the following example.

```
htmlist = ['<div class="portal" role="navigation" id="p-coll-print_export">',\
           '<h3>Print/export</h3>',\
           '<div class="body">',\
           '<ul>',\
           '<li id="coll-create_a_book"><a href="/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&amp;bookcmd=book_creator&amp;referer=Main+Page">Create a book</a></li>',\
           '<li id="coll-download-as-rl"><a href="/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&amp;bookcmd=render_article&amp;arttitle=Main+Page&amp;oldid=560327612&amp;writer=rl">Download as PDF</a></li>',\
           '<li id="t-print"><a href="/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&amp;printable=yes" title="Printable version of this page [p]" accesskey="p">Printable version</a></li>',\
           '</ul>',\
           '</div>',\
           '</div>',\
          ]

soup = __import__("bs4").BeautifulSoup("".join(htmlist), "html.parser")

for x in soup("a"):
    print(x)
    print(x.attrs)
    print(soup.a.get_text())
```

I was expecting this short script to print the `a` tag equaling `x`, followed by a dictionary of the attributes of `x` (name (as key) and content (as key's value) of each of these), ending with the text for the link.

Instead the output is

```
<a href="/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&amp;bookcmd=book_creator&amp;referer=Main+Page">Create a book</a>
{'href': '/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&bookcmd=book_creator&referer=Main+Page'}
Create a book
<a href="/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&amp;bookcmd=render_article&amp;arttitle=Main+Page&amp;oldid=560327612&amp;writer=rl">Download as PDF</a>
{'href': '/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&bookcmd=render_article&arttitle=Main+Page&oldid=560327612&writer=rl'}
Create a book
<a accesskey="p" href="/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&amp;printable=yes" title="Printable version of this page [p]">Printable version</a>
{'href': '/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&printable=yes', 'title': 'Printable version of this page [p]', 'accesskey': ['p']}
Create a book
```

The issues I find with this output are:

- `print(soup.a.get_text())` bit always prints the text of the first tag.
- In the dictionaries output by `print(x.attrs)`, the value of the key `"href"` is missing `&amp.`

What am I missing here and how do I get the desired output?

Comment: Why don't you use `x.get_text()`? Also `&amp;` is the html encoded version of `&`,  i wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @t.m.adam Of course I should be getting the text from `x`, thanks. I still need the `&amp;` part, though. This is part of a challenge and I need the output to match.

Comment: @t.m.adam Quick question. As you can see I added a solution that replaces & with &amp;, but I just realised this is potentially incorrect because the link might have legit ampersands. My question is:

Comment: That is very unlikely. A url that contains ampersands for reasons other than separating parameters in the query string is propably a badly formatted url.

Comment: @t.m.adam Ooops, my comment was cut short, glad you understood my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`cgi.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) or [`html.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) methods to html encode the `&` character.

```
import html

for x in soup("a"):
    print(x)
    print({k:html.escape(v, False) if k == 'href' else v for k,v in x.attrs.items()})
    print(x.get_text())
```